# Removing string to the right of a character using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a string field and I want to delete the part of the string after a specific character in this case a '/'. I am looking for a way to do this using the field calculator in QGIS.

I know I can use the replace function to replace a specific string but I need a way to do this with a wildcard as the strings after the '/' character are not the same in the table.

Comment: Would you like to remove the / as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with the field calculator function `regexp_replace()` on a **NEW field** like:
`regexp_replace("input_field",'(/.*$)','/')`

That one will keep the / but if you want the / removed, use:
`regexp_replace("test_regex",'(/.*$)','')`

Explanation:
The regular expression being used is `/.*$`

`/` --look for a forward slash

`.` --identify any character *(strings/numbers/special)* after the slash except newlines

`*` --keep searching for any characters after the slash

`$` --until the end of the string is reached

Comment: Thank you! This worked great and your explanation is very thorough!