# Removing part of string from the right in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, string, regular-expression

I am trying to remove the last piece of my string in QGIS.

[image]

I want to delete the E10 from the end.

I tried both:

[How to easily edit attribute data using Regular Expressions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40637/how-to-easily-edit-attribute-data-using-regular-expressions)

```
 regexp_replace("UPRN", 'E*', '')
```

as well as

```
 regexp_replace("UPRN", 'E10', '')
```

but I get only pure 1.000 value.

In this approach:

[Removing string to the right of a character using QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240812/removing-string-to-the-right-of-a-character-using-qgis-field-calculator)

I tried:

```
 regexp_replace("UPRN", ('E*'), '')
```

and

```
 regexp_replace("UPRN", ('E*'), '')
```

but it still throws 1.0000 only.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be E.*, surely?

Comment: What is the precision of your UPRN4 field, do all the decimals fit or are they truncated to 1.000?

Comment: The precision is as you can see on the left. About 8 decimals...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `.` after the `E`; in other words, the token for a character following the `E`:

```
regexp_replace(string, 'E.*', '')
```

[image]

There are a lot of ways to make the pattern more surgical. You could use `\d` if you want to match an `E` and any digits that follow it:

```
regexp_replace(string, 'E\d*', '')
```

You can also use + rather than * to ensure you only match to literal `E` that are actually followed by at least one digit:

```
regexp_replace(string, 'E\d+', '')
```

Just depends on how much variation there is in your strings.

P.S. It also wouldn't surprise me if you're saving the results in a float, rather than a string field. Might explain the case where you get 1.000 as your result

Comment: I saved these results as a float exactly. Your code is working. Thanks. How about the single dot removal from the string?

Comment: As '.' is a special character in regex, you need to use a backslash to escape it. e.g. regex_replace(string,'\.','')

Comment: I've already sorted it in a different way. Many thanks for your help :)